# group and have more than one value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i find how many ids having type ids more than one..

```
Id Name Type_id
1  A    11
1  B    11
1  A    22
1  C    22
2  A    11
2  B    11
3  A    22
3  C    22
4  A    11
4  B    22
```

I need an out put which of the ids have more than one type id, in above example, Id 1 and 4 has more than one type ids 11,22

Output

```
Id  
1   
4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(type_id) <> max(type_id);
```

This is pretty much a direct translation of your description.  (Note:  You *can* use `count(distinct)` as well but that incurs more overhead.)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Id
FROM name_table
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type_id) > 1
```

In this query your are grouping all the record which have the same id, but just print the ones that have more than one distinct type_id

Comment: Good, Gordon solution is more efficient